# What usage of とは is this?

Tags: meaning

What is the とは in the below sentence? 　I was thinking that it could be something like 彼とは相性がいい but because he says 俺たち afterwards this doesn't sound right.

> 以前翔も言っていたが、打てば響くを地で行く可憐**とは**、本当に俺たち相性がいいのかもしれない

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's part of (～は)～と相性がいい. This とは is と meaning "with" followed by は, the topic/contrast marker.

- 俺たち(は)可憐と相性がいい。
  We get along well with Karen.
- 俺たち(は)可憐とは相性がいい。 (added は)
- 可憐とは俺たち(は)相性がいい。 (changed word order)

<sub>(So this clause has two は-marked arguments. This normally means one of them is contrastive, but in this case I feel almost no contrastive nuance in 可憐とは. I personally feel "double-topic" sentences like this can exist, but I may be wrong.)</sub>

Comment: I should probably clarify why I didn't think it was とは相性がいい. I understand from context the 俺たち to refer to himself and 可憐 and not himself and 翔.